# How Do We Convert HTML to PDF using Python, Is there Any code please share it to me?

Tags: python, pdf, data-science, converters, html2pdf

I have tried the Library called pytotree, But i didnt get any Answer
This is the code:

```
import pdftotree
file= open('C:/Users/chaitanya.naidu/Downloads/test.pdf', 'rb')
f = pdftotree.parse(file)
```

I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-4-4a9a6b72801d>", line 1, in <module>
    f = pdftotree.parse(file)
  File "C:\Users\chaitanya.naidu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdftotree\core.py", line 63, in parse
    if not extractor.is_scanned():
  File "C:\Users\chaitanya.naidu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdftotree\TreeExtract.py", line 121, in is_scanned
    self.parse()
  File "C:\Users\chaitanya.naidu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdftotree\TreeExtract.py", line 91, in parse
    for page_num, layout in enumerate(analyze_pages(self.pdf_file)):
  File "C:\Users\chaitanya.naidu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdftotree\utils\pdf\pdf_utils.py", line 117, in analyze_pages
    with open(os.path.realpath(file_name), "rb") as fp:
  File "C:\Users\chaitanya.naidu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\ntpath.py", line 542, in abspath
    path = os.fspath(path)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.BufferedReader
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pdfkit](https://pypi.org/project/pdfkit/), example:

```
import pdfkit

pdfkit.from_url('http://google.com', 'out.pdf')
pdfkit.from_file('test.html', 'out.pdf')
pdfkit.from_string('Hello!', 'out.pdf')
```